# How do you access an external file from within qemu-system-m68k

Tags: qemu

Firstly I'm a real QEMU newbie.
Using QEMU in the reimplementation of an old m68k operating system.

I can't figure out how to access, read or write an attached filesystem file image.
I really don't know even where to begin.

I'm using QEMU 4.0

```
qemu-system-m68k -m 8M -cpu m68000 -kernel os.68k -drive file=fs.68k,format=raw  -s -S -serial stdio
```

The **QEMU monitor** "info block" displays

> ```
>   none0 (#block105): fs.68k (raw)
>      Removable device: not locked, tray closed
>      Cache mode:       writeback
> ```

All the examples I have come across to date are for x86 which has IDE support.
qemu-system-m68k does not have out of the box IDE support.

I want to know how, from within the QEMU m68k emulator, to read and write an external file.
 Once I understand it, I can code a driver.

Answer (score 0):

As of QEMU 4.0 (and the upcoming 4.1), all the m68k machines QEMU provides are devboard/SoC models of Coldfire systems which do not support any kind of block device (ie no IDE or SCSI disk, no SD card) or any pluggable buses like PCI or USB. So the only thing you can do with them is load guest images via -kernel -- they have no storage.

Using a -drive option the way you have creates a drive for QEMU, but does not connect it up to anything. Effectively you've asked QEMU to produce a model of a setup where you have the real hardware development board on your desk, with a hard disk sat next to it, but no way to plug the disk into the board.

There are some patches on the QEMU development mailing list which add support for emulating a NeXTcube machine. They will probably get merged some time after QEMU 4.1 is released (so later in 2019, aiming for the 4.2 release at the end of the year). That hardware includes support for disk drives, so once those have landed, they will probably be more suitable for what you want to do than any of the current m68k boards.